# twig how to include a twig in an existing div

Tags: templating, include, vue

My project now contain many twig and vue file, and I want to add a footer in every page.

Every twig file will `{% extends '_base/index.twig' %}` so I want to include footer.twig in index.twig so that every page will display footer by just including it one time only.

My problem is I want to include my twig inside an existing div  `"body_show"` in vue but I cant do it.The approach I am using now will create a new div instead of including it inside the existing div.

How can I include footer.twig in `<div id="body_show" class="box_l">` in vue?

home.vue:

```
<template>
<div id="body_show" class="box_l">

</div>
</template>
```

index.twig:

```
 <div id="main-wrapper" class="container-fluid">
   <div id="content-wrapper" class="row">
     {% block  body_show %}
       {% include '_base/footer.twig' %}
     {% endblock %}
   </div>
</div>
```

home.twig:

```
{% extends '_base/index.twig' %}

{% block body_show %}
    {% include '_base/footer.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```